# Visual C++ Static Multi-Threaded CF lacking in newer VS

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2005

I have a COM+ application which builds and run under Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2005 libraries, which I am trying to port to a newer VS version. So I first tried with a new SDK for Windows, which failed in the registration phase. After, I tried with VS 2010 Express SP1, which also failed in the app registration phase.

While investigating why the app works with VS2005 and not works with VS2010, I discovered that the VS2005 installation has the following libraries (actually if I install only this, the app COM registration works clean), which I did not find as the other one, in the VS2010:

```
 +- Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Professional Edition
    +- Visual C++
       +- Visual C++ Run-Time Libraries
          +- Visual C++ Static Multi-Threaded CF
```

So I tried also to get the Visual C++ Static Multi-Threaded CF for VS2010, but no success. I only found several versions of redistributable libraries which did not work.

The error when I try to register the application is the 0xc0150002 ("The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0150002). Clock OK to close the application"). I also looked for this error, but it seemed to be very generic, and no other clues were found.

Does someone know how to solve this? Please!

**Update 1**

Looking in the Windows Event Viewer / Customs Views / Administrative Events, I found the following error:

> Activation context generation failed for
>   "C:\Users\root\Desktop\OMNI\bin\BLK_ENTRY.dll".Error in manifest or
>   policy file
>   "C:\Users\root\Desktop\OMNI\bin\Microsoft.VC80.OpenMP.MANIFEST" on
>   line 5. Component identity found in manifest does not match the
>   identity of the component requested. Reference is
>   Microsoft.VC80.OpenMP,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.762".
>   Definition is
>   Microsoft.VC80.OpenMP,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.42".
>   Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.

**Update 2**

Looking at the same event log, I found the following error (before trying to install reinstall the libraries)

> Activation context generation failed for
>   "C:\Users\root\Desktop\OMNI\bin\BLK_ENTRY.dll". Dependent Assembly
>   Microsoft.VC80.OpenMP,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.762"
>   could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.

Comment: Look in the Windows Application event log for a detailed diagnostic for this error.  Fairly predictable, you should of course not have a dependency on the VS2005 runtime libraries anymore.  Rebuild *all* libraries you link.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant. Looking for in the Event Viewer I found that a library calls the component Microsoft.VC80.OpenMP. Unfortunately this library cannot be rebuild.

Comment: I will complement the question with errors details.